# Azure Policy for Naming

Tags: json, azure, azure-policy

I'm doing something incorrectly here regarding an Azure Policy I'm creating.  Trying to create a naming policy that blocks creation of a resource (in this case a resource group) that doesn't match.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "mode": "All",
        "displayName": "Company Naming Convention - Resource Groups",
        "description": "This policy governs the naming standard for resource groups and should be assigned at the resource group scope.  The naming scheme is rg-region-workload name-environment-optional instance number'.",
        "metadata": {
            "category": "Governance"
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups" 
                    },
                    {
                    "allOf": [
                        
                            {
                                "field": "name",
                                "notLike": "rg-useast-*"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "name",
                                "notLike": "rg-useast2-*"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "name",
                                "notLike": "rg-uscentral-*"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "name",
                                "notLike": "rg-uksouth-*"
                            }
                        
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "field": "name",
                                "notLike": "*-production.###"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "name",
                                "notLike": "*-development.###"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "name",
                                "notLike": "*-qualityassurance.###"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "name",
                                "notLike": "*-testing.###"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd ALSO like to create a policy to audit existing resources that don't match this name, but I can address that later.  Anyone have a suggestion what I'm doing wrong or a better way to go about this?

Comment: So what happens when you implement this policy?  Does  it not block creating a resource group with the wrong naming?

Comment: no, afraid not.  did absolutely nothing when I tested it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... so the original policy works great... if I actually looked at the right resource.  Should be "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups" not "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups".  Dang do I feel like an idiot...

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect syntax in your Azure Policy Definition. The allOf syntax  requires all conditions to be true and you can keep all the conditions in single allOf Operator.

Modified version of Policy for reference :

```
{
    "properties": {
        "mode": "All",
        "displayName": "Company Naming Convention - Resource Groups",
        "description": "This policy governs the naming standard for resource groups and should be assigned at the resource group scope.  The naming scheme is rg-region-workload name-environment-optional instance number'.",
        "metadata": {
            "category": "Governance"
        },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "field": "type",
                        "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "notLike": "rg-useast-*"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "notLike": "rg-useast2-*"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "notLike": "rg-uscentral-*"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "notLike": "rg-uksouth-*"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "notLike": "*-production.###"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "notLike": "*-development.###"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "notLike": "*-qualityassurance.###"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "notLike": "*-testing.###"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "deny"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note, it takes around 30 minutes for the assignment to be applied to the defined scope. For more information on evaluation cycle of Azure Policy, refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data#evaluation-triggers).

For on-demand evaluation , use az cli command : [az policy state trigger-scan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/policy/state?view=azure-cli-latest#az_policy_state_trigger_scan)

Comment: Let me give that a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Still doesn't quite seem to be working, but also this policy isn't going to do exactly what I want.  theoretically, someone could use just the first half of the naming convention but not the second half with this policy.