# Azure Policy to enfore naming convention on resource group has no effect

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Why has the following policy no effect? I was expecting it to prevent the creation of any resource group that doesn't start with `rg-*`. However, any pattern for a resource group name can be used.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
          },
          {
            "field": "name",
            "notLike": "rg-*"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/subscriptions/.../providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/policy-naming-convention-rg",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "policy-naming-convention-rg"
}
```

It is correctly assigned and also I've waited long enough so it had time to become effective. An ARM template that can be used to create a resource group looks as follows:

So the type should match, and field also. I am puzzled. Any idea?

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "parameters": {
        "rgName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {}
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
            "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
            "properties": {},
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808877/azure-policy-for-naming), I think it could be of help. Basically, you need to use `Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups` not `Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups` when defining your policy.

It is not exactly your use case, but the Microsoft Azure provides [an example](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/69a4c0343157ca925ee56874ce73423246cb59b9/articles/governance/policy/tutorials/govern-tags.md#deny-resource-groups-missing-the-costcenter-tag) of Azure Policies related to resource groups in which the mentioned naming convention is used.